# Getting data in a date range from database

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I always store my dates as a unix timestamp in the database. Now I have two dates:
Start date and End date for some images I would like to show on the website. The image should be visible on the "Start date" and disappear once the "End date" is reached.

I use this simple query at this moment:

```
SELECT name, image, link
FROM exclusive
WHERE CURDATE( ) >= from_unixtime( start_date, '%d-%m-%Y' )  
AND CURDATE( ) <= from_unixtime( end_date, '%d-%m-%Y' )
AND category = 'movies'
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

But this is returning an empty result every time, although there are two fields within the data range.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need to specify the format to `FROM_UNIXTIME()`, and indeed you're giving the wrong format. Should be yyyy-mm-dd, not dd-mm-yyyy, `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: Michael: This will sound weird, but I'm using the jquery datepicker. And the format I chose there is d-m-Y. I know the default format should be Y-m-d, but in the country I live in we work with a different date format. So even after doing what you just suggested it still doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: just convert it before query

Comment: @moonwalker you're not storing the dates as strings on the database, right? time comparisons (tricky as they can be) should be locale-independent; so you should compare in a locale-independent space, like timestamps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of formatting, use the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to remove the time part of your timestamps:

```
SELECT name, image, link
FROM exclusive
WHERE 
    CURDATE( ) BETWEEN DATE(from_unixtime( start_date ) )
    AND DATE(from_unixtime( end_date ) )
    AND category = 'movies'
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it has the added advantage that you'll actually be able to use any indexes you might have on start and end date.

```
SELECT name, image, link
FROM exclusive
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
AND category = 'movies'
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

Comment: This includes the time portion of the timestamp in the comparison, which it seems like the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Michael - If so, then your answer is correct, but I'm not 100% sure that's the case based on his question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're doing the comparison as string types, not as timestamp.  Therefore, the format matters.  Changing to yyyy-mm-dd makes it work (because the most significant part, the year, is at the left).

But much better, and optimizable with indexes is to compare as timestamps.

```
WHERE start_date <= unix_timestamp(curdate())
    AND end_date >= unit_timestamp(curdate())
```

or, for some SQL engines, use the BETWEEN operator:

```
WHERE unix_timestamp(curdate()) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Comment: +1... I really like the use of `to_unixtime` to avoid obfuscating any indexes.

Comment: I like this solution too, but unfortunately Javier, I keep getting an error in my database "FUNCTION myDatabase.to_unixtime does not exist".

Comment: @moonwalker What if you try the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function instead?

Comment: @moonwalker: i'm assuming you only want to compare to the current date and not time.  if you want the whole timestamp, use `unix_timestamp()` without arguments